# Connect to AWS RDS Proxy from Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

In an EC2 instance, I have succeed connecting to "AWS MySQL RDS" from Java, since the typical jdbc technique has been used for that purpose.

However, I cannot be able to use the Preview of "Mysql RDS Proxy" from my java code, because no documentation at all about this matter.

I found this: https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/ but it uses JS and it does not help for me to understand how can I do it in Java.

So, my question is: where can I get info about using "AWS Mysql RDS Proxy" from my java code? (note that I will run that code from inside of a EC2 instance)

Comment: did u get it working? I am struggling with that as well

Comment: Yeah, I did !!!!! :)

Comment: Can you give me a hand on how to do that?

Comment: Sure. Take a look at my own answer. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I had to do nothing. If you connect to the RDS just like you do with the normal proxy, everything will work as expected. So, you dont need to do anything special. Create (on aws console) configure (on aws console) and Use (in your client code) "RDS proxy" just like the "normal" RDS" and it will work. That's it.

Comment: could you please provide java snippet for the same?